# Language specific custom syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

So I have to follow a name convention for my C data types :

Typedefs must start with a `t_` prefix such a `t_mytype`.

Structs must start with a with an `s_` prefix and so on for other data types.

So I added `syn match cType /\(\s\|^\|(\)s_\w\+/` to my `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/c.vim` file and it is working almost as intended except that when in front of a parenthesis, the parenthesis is also highlighted.

This is minor annoyance but I would very much like to know what I am doing wrong. What can I do to exclude that paenthesis from higlighting ?

Thanks in advance dear vimmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write language specific highlighting commands in a `your_favorite_language.vim` file in `~/.vim/after/syntax`.
In your case `c.vim`.

The reason for putting it there is that it will remain there across vim/distro updates.

For C, the command goes like this :

```
syn match cType /some_vim_regex_pattern/
```

The vim regex pattern for a word is `\<word\>`. That's a convenient abstraction because you don't have to care if you word has start of the line (`\^`), whitespace  (`\s`), parentheses or any other non-word delimiter before/after it.

So in your case, you want :

```
syn match cType /\<t_\w\+\>/
```

If you want to know wore about vim's regular expressions here is a useful link :
http://www.vimregex.com/

Comment: PS you should probably use `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`; if you update the distribution files, your change will get blown away.